# Aurelia common class/model

Tags: aurelia

I'm trying to implement a globally-accessible singular class in an Aurelia project.  The purposes are to (a) store singulares/states like current user ID/name/permissions, (b) load and store common data like enum lists and key-value pairs for drop-down lists across the whole app, (c) store commonly-used functions like wrappers for Http-Fetch client, (d) configure and then update i18n locale, (e) global keyboard listener for hotkeys throughout the app.  Here's what I have so far:

**/src/resources/components/core.js**:

```
import 'fetch';
import { HttpClient, json } from 'aurelia-fetch-client';
import { inject } from 'aurelia-framework';
import { EventAggregator } from 'aurelia-event-aggregator';
import { BindingSignaler } from 'aurelia-templating-resources';
import { I18N } from 'aurelia-i18n';
import * as store from 'store';

@inject(EventAggregator, BindingSignaler, I18N, HttpClient)
export class Core {

  constructor(eventAggregator, bindingSignaler, i18n, httpClient) {
    // store local handles
    this.eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
    this.bindingSignaler = bindingSignaler;
    this.i18n = i18n;

    // initialize singulars
    this.UserID = 1;
    this.lang = 'es';
    this.yr = 78;
    this.qtr = 1;

    // set up httpClient
    httpClient.configure(config => {
      config
        .withBaseUrl('http://localhost:8080/api/v1');
    });
    this.httpClient = httpClient;

    // listen for Ctrl+S or Ctrl+Enter and publish event
    window.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
      if (event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey) { // Ctrl + ___
        if ((event.keyCode == 83) || (event.keyCode == 115) || (event.keyCode == 10) || (event.keyCode == 13)) {  // Ctrl+Enter or Ctrl+S
          // Save button... publish new event
          event.preventDefault();
          this.eventAggregator.publish('ewKeyboardShortcutSave', true);
        }
        if ((event.keyCode == 77) || (event.keyCode == 109)) {  // Ctrl+M
          // New button... publish new event
          event.preventDefault();
          this.eventAggregator.publish('ewKeyboardShortcutNew', true);
        }
      }
    });

    // load enumData
    $.getJSON("../../locales/" + this.lang + "/enum.json", (json) => { this.enum = json; });
    this.getTableKeys();
    this.getEnumCats();
  }

  getData(url) {
    // Http Fetch Client to retreive data (GET)
    return this.httpClient.fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.json());
  }

  postData(url, data, use_method = 'post') {
    // Http Fetch Client to send data (POST/PUT/DELETE)
    return this.httpClient.fetch(url, {
      method: use_method,
      body: json(data)
    }).then(response => {
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw Error(response.statusText);
      }
      return response;
    });
  }

  getTableKeys() {
    // retrieve list of table keys from database API
    this.getData('/keys').then(response => {
      this.keys = response;
    });
  }

  getEnumCats() {
    // retrieve list of enum cats from database API
    this.getData('/enums').then(response => {
      this.cats = response;
    });
  }

  setLang(lang) {
    if (lang) {
      this.lang = lang;
    }
    // set i18n locale
    this.i18n.setLocale(this.lang);
    // load enumData
    $.getJSON("../../locales/" + this.lang + "/enum.json", (json) => {
      this.enumData = json;
    });
    // publish new event
    this.eventAggregator.publish('ewLang', lang);
    this.bindingSignaler.signal('ewLang');
  }
}
```

Here's the **/src/resources/index.js** for the resources feature:

```
export function configure(config) {

  // value converters
  config.globalResources([
    './value-converters/currency-format-value-converter',
    './value-converters/number-format-value-converter',
    './value-converters/date-format-value-converter',
    './value-converters/checkbox-value-converter',
    './value-converters/keys-value-converter',
    './value-converters/enum-value-converter',
    './value-converters/table-key-value-converter'
    ]);

  // custom elements
  config.globalResources([
    './elements/enum-list',
    './elements/modal-form'
    ]);

  // common/core components
  config.globalResources([
    './components/core'
    ]);
}
```

which is in turn activated in my **main.js** like this:

```
export function configure(aurelia) {
  aurelia.use
    .standardConfiguration()
    .feature('resources')
    // .plugin('aurelia-dialog') // not working
    .plugin('aurelia-validation')
    .plugin('aurelia-i18n', (instance) => {
      // register backend plugin
      instance.i18next.use(XHR);
      instance.setup({
        backend: {                                  
          loadPath: '/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json',
        },
        lng : 'en',
        ns: ['translation'],
        defaultNS: 'translation',
        attributes : ['t'],
        fallbackLng : 'en',
        debug : false
      });
    });

  aurelia.start().then(a => a.setRoot());
}
```

**Questions:**

1. It's not working.  I get two errors: `vendor-bundle.js:3777 Uncaught TypeError: h.load is not a function` and `Unhandled rejection Error: Load timeout for modules: template-registry-entry!resources/components/core.html,text!resources/components/core.html`.  Any idea why it's trying to find a core.html when I only need the core.js component?
2. Is it even possible to globally inject this type of class in a way that my viewmodels don't need to inject it but can still access the properties, or do I still need to inject this file everywhere?
3. Is the filename **core.js** and the class name **Core** acceptable naming conventions?  Is the location inside /src/resources/components a good choice? I had to create the components subfolder.
4. Any other suggestions for better best practices?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Question 1**

When you do this:

```
config.globalResources([
'./components/core'
]);
```

Aurelia will try to load a pair of view and view-model, respectively **core.js** and **core.html**, unless if the component is declared as a "view-model only component". Like this:

```
import { noView } from 'aurelia-framework';

@noView
@inject(EventAggregator, BindingSignaler, I18N, HttpClient)
export class Core {
}
```

In the above case Aurelia won't try to load "core.html" because the component is declared with `noView`.

**Question 2**

As far as I know, you have to `inject` or `<require>` it everywhere, but the latter doesn't apply in your case, so you have to `inject`. You could some trickery to avoid the injecting but I would not recommend.

**Question 3**

The file name **core.js** and the class name `Core` are not only acceptable but the correct aurelia-way of doing this. However, I don't think that "/resources/components" is a good a location because it's not a component, not even a "resource". I would move this to another folder.

In addition, remove these lines:

```
config.globalResources([
'./components/core'
]);
```

Resources were made to be used inside views, which is not you are case.

**Question 4**

The file **core.js** seems to be a very import piece of code of your application. I would leave it inside the root folder, next to **main.js**. (THIS IS MY OPINION)

Also, if you need to set some specific properties in your `Core` object, you can instantiate it inside the **main.js**. Something like this:

```
export function configure(aurelia) {
   //...

   Core core = new Core(); //<--- put necessary parameters
   //some default configuration
   aurelia.container.registerInstance(Core, core);      

  aurelia.start().then(a => a.setRoot());
}
```

Now, you can inject the `core` object using the `@inject` decorator and all classe will have the same instance of `Core`. More information at http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/dependency-injection/latest/dependency-injection-basics/1

Hope this helps!

Comment: Fabio, thanks so much for such a thorough response. If I could invite it 10 times I would.

Comment: In the line `Core core = new Core(); //<--- put necessary parameters`, 2 questions: (1) Is this TypeScript? I'm using ESNext and thinking I would drop the first Core? (2) Based on the code of core.js, there wouldn't be any parameters or default configuration, right?

Comment: I'm getting an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'configure' of undefined at new Core`.  I wonder if the "necessary parameters" is related but I don't know what those are or how to fix it.

Comment: That is just an example you can use if the `Core` class has parameters in the constructors... You wouldn't drop the first core because at this time there is no core yet... Yes, based on the code of core.js there's no default configuration, you can skip that step